# Caddy isn't working and full connection is working fine

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, caddy, caddyfile

So Caddy was running normally until I wrote the command caddy run,
and now it is failing

```
● caddy.service - Caddy
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/caddy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-10-27 05:58:17 UTC; 17s ago
       Docs: https://caddyserver.com/docs/
    Process: 4797 ExecStart=/usr/bin/caddy run --environ --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 4797 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: LOGNAME=caddy
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: USER=caddy
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: INVOCATION_ID=afc5a1ce30c84edea03ff0e9e3aee0ca
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: JOURNAL_STREAM=9:53625
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: {"level":"info","ts":1635314297.0703933,"msg":"using provided configuration","confi>Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen systemd[1]: Started Caddy.
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen caddy[4797]: run: loading initial config: loading new config: starting caddy administration endp>Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen systemd[1]: caddy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 27 05:58:17 haneen systemd[1]: caddy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 27 05:58:34 haneen systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. >~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

and this caused an issue that the website isn't working,
and this is my caddy file

[caddyFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhOgq.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.